# Having trouble setting up ngtemplate-loader and webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, webpacker

I've tried setting up the webpack loader by adding this to the webpack/loaders directory

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    test: /\.html$/,
    loaders: [`ngtemplate?relativeTo=${path.join(__dirname, "/app")}`, "html"] //html?attrs[]=div:ng-include
}
```

and then requiring the appropriate template file from the .js code.

```
templateUrl: require('ngtemplate!html!./app/views/environment/index.html')
```

but I get the following error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'html' in '/Users/joe/testrails5.1/app/javascript/app/scripts'
resolve 'html' in '/Users/joe/testrails5.1/app/javascript/app/scripts'
  Parsed request is a module
```

Does this work for anyone else? I'm using angular 1.6 so do I need to use a different module?